# Assign grid boxes to a user in a circular pattern around the reserved center box

Tags: java, math, formula

I am trying to figure out a solution/scalable formula/way to assign boxes of a 2D grid to a user.

So let's assume I am using an infinite grid. But there is a center point (0, 0) will be its coordinates. This box will never be assigned.

I need to start from a point outside of that box, (0, 1) let's say, for the first user to be assigned a box on the grid. Then it will move onto (1, 1) for the next user, and (1, 0) for the next, and so on so forth.

Then once all boxes around the origin point have been claimed, move onto the next "layer", e.g. [(2, 2), (2, 1), (2, 0)].

Sorry If this question has been asked before, I don't know what you would really call this.

Also: I am storing how many boxes have been assigned and information like that as-well.

[image: Grid Visualization]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the most efficient and concise way will be to generate in advance all the coordinates of a given layer into a list. that way it becomes a simple algorithm of permutations of pairs of numbers.

here's a method that will generate all permutations of pairs for given `n` from `-n` to `n` and excluding pair `[0,0]` . I am using `Pair` class from Apache commons library

```
public List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> generateAllPerm(int n) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(Math.abs(n)*-1, Math.abs(n))
        .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.rangeClosed(Math.abs(n)*-1, Math.abs(n))
            .filter(j -> i != 0 || j != 0)
            .mapToObj(j -> new ImmutablePair<Integer, Integer>(i, j))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
        ).flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```